# AbstractValidator Vs OnActionExecuting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I was setting culture language in `OnActionExecuting`. But my validation method(FluentValidation) is executing even before `OnActionExecuting` executes. But I need culture language needed in `AbstractValidator`, before `OnActionExecuting`.

```
internal class MeetingAbstractValidator : AbstractValidator<MeetingAbstract>
{
    public MeetingAbstractValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.SPEPaperNumberText)
          .NotEmpty()
          .When(IfValueIsYes)
          .WithMessage(i18n_Models_Abstract.RequiredField);
     }
 }  

private bool IfValueIsYes(MeetingAbstract model)
  {
      return model.HasMaterialPublishedBySPEText.Equals(i18n_Models_Abstract.AbstractYes);
   }


public class LanguageFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
      var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
      string cultureName = null;
      var cultureCookie = request.Cookies["_culture"];
      if (request.UserLanguages != null)
           cultureName = cultureCookie != null ? cultureCookie.Value : 
                    request.UserLanguages[0];
           cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName); // This is safe
           Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new 
                               System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
          Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
     }
}
```

How to handle this? Can I override `OnActionExecuting`?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use **Application_BeginRequest** event and place your culture logic there. That executes on the integrated pipeline level, long before MVC is event delegated to handle the request.